# The line through the incenter and circumcenter of $\triangle ABC$ is perpendicular to the median from $A$ iff $\frac2{BC}=\frac1{AB}+\frac1{AC}$

Tags: geometry, contest-math, triangles

> Given triangle $ABC$, $O$ and $I$ are circumcenter and incenter, respectively, and $M$ is the midpoint of segment $BC$. Prove that $OI$ is perpendicular to $AM$ if and only if
> $$\dfrac{2}{BC}=\dfrac{1}{AB}+\dfrac{1}{AC}$$

Please give me the strategy with this geometry problem, as I quite don't know what to do with the circumcenter and incenter.

Comment: even if you don.t know how to start you can give a background :for example mentioning the source , diagram or even what you understand /properties you know about a circumcenter

Answer (score 0):

[image]

$\require{begingroup} \begingroup$
$\def\i{\mathbf{i}}\def\Re{\operatorname{Re}}$
Let $|BC|=a$, $|AC|=b$, $|AB|=c$,
$|BM|=|CM|=\tfrac12\,a$.

Considering the vertices $A,B,C$ of triangle as complex numbers,
let

\begin{align} 
B&=(0,0)=0
,\quad
C=(a,0)=a
,\quad
A=(u,v)=u+v\cdot\i
,\quad
M=\tfrac12\,(B+C)=\tfrac12\,a
\tag{1}\label{1}
.
\end{align}

Then the coordinates of the incenter $I$
and the circumcenter $O$
can be found as

\begin{align}
I&=\frac{a\,A+b\,B+c\,C}{a+b+c}
=
\frac{a(u+c)}{a+b+c}+\frac{av}{a+b+c}\,\i
\tag{2}\label{2}
,\\
O&=
\frac{a^2\,(b^2+c^2-a^2)\,A+b^2\,(a^2+c^2-b^2)\,B+c^2\,(b^2+a^2-c^2)\,C}
{a^2\,(b^2+c^2-a^2)+b^2\,(a^2+c^2-b^2)+c^2\,(b^2+a^2-c^2)}
\\
&=
\frac{a(au(b^2+c^2-a^2)+c^2(a^2+b^2-c^2))}{(a+b+c)(-a+b+c)(a-b+c)(a+b-c)}
+\frac{a^2v(b^2+c^2-a^2)}{(a+b+c)(-a+b+c)(a-b+c)(a+b-c)}
\,\i
\tag{3}\label{3}
.
\end{align}

In case when $OI\perp AM$, we must have

\begin{align}
\Re\left(
\frac{O-I}{A-M}
\right)&=0
\tag{4}\label{4}
.
\end{align}

Using
\begin{align}
v&=\sqrt{c^2-u^2}
\tag{5}\label{5}
,\\
u &=c\cos\angle ABC
=\frac{a^2-b^2+c^2}{2a}
\tag{6}\label{6}
,
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\Re\left(
\frac{O-I}{A-M}
\right)&=
\frac{2bc-a(b+c)}{2b^2-a^2+2c^2}
\tag{7}\label{7}
,
\end{align}

so the condition \eqref{4} holds
(that is, $OI\perp AM$) when

\begin{align}
a&=\frac{2bc}{b+c}
\tag{8}\label{8}
,
\end{align}

as expected.

$\endgroup$